# Get template name by full URL

Tags: template-include

Is There Any Way to get the template Name By full URL
for example

If the full url is

```
www.example.com/hello-world
```

I need a function that return the template name (`page.php`)

I know that WordPress matches every url with regular expression to determine the query and decide which template to include.

That's exactly what I need, a built in or (custom made) function that takes the URL
and returns back the corresponding template

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the global `$template` which holds the complete path of the current template being use to display a page. From there you can manipulate the value to get the name of the template

As example, the value of `$template` looks like this: (*This is on my localhost on my PC*)

```
E:\xammp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/themes/pietergoosen2014/page-test.php
```

To only return the `page-test.php` part, I use the following function which uses the PHP functions `substr` and `strrpos` which finds the last `/` character in URL and then returns everything after that:

```
function get_current_template() {
    global $template;
    return substr( $template, strrpos( $template, '/' ) + 1 );
}
```

You can then use it anywhere in your template like

```
echo get_current_template();
```

I usually just print the template name in my site's header on my localhost like

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () 
{
    global $template;
    print substr( $template, strrpos( $template, '/' ) + 1 );
});
```

or

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () 
{
    global $template;
    print $template;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [`get_page_template_slug()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template_slug)

And since that function requires an id instead of a URL, use [`url_to_postid()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid) to find the ID first

Comment: i was hoping for a general function that works with all url
your suggestion will only work for page and post url
not for other url`s likes
archive and search

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in header.php to know the current template:

```
<body id="<?php echo get_option('current_page_template'); ?>">
```

I'd be happy if this helps.