# Locating the template behind a WordPress Page

Tags: templates

Is there a way to tell from a WordPress page what template the page was built from.   In my case, there's a page at mysite.com/checkout and I happen to know that the template used to build this page is at wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php. But how could I have known that just from poking around the page with Chrome Dev Tools?

Thanks

Comment: There is no way AFAIK to show this in Chrome Dev Tools, I always have a custom function that runs on my dev site locally which prints the template being used for a specific page load. You can check it out [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/204472/31545)

Comment: By default, WordPress adds page template file name in body classes unless of course you disallow it. You can view body classes in source code.

Comment: That´s not really default behaviour, it´s quite specific to the theme you use.

Comment: Peter: I tried your add_action( 'wp_head', function () 
{
    global $template;
    print $template;
});  but this displays the template for the parent theme (genesis) not the ". . . checkout/form-checkout.php" template that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea - have you tried putting something like this:

```
<?php 
   if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
       echo get_option('current_page_template'); 
   } ?>
```

You may be able to put it in the header so admins can see the template names of every page - although without testing I'm not sure - may have to go in the actual template files.